# How to interpret YearMonth date in 20th century?

Tags: java, java-time

How can I force `YearMonth` to interpret a two-digit value as 20th century?

`YearMonth.of(16, 11); //result: 0016-11`

But I'd like to get: `2016-11`.

Of course I could just add `2000` to any year digit before, but maybe there is a more correct way?

Comment: More correct than `YearMonth.of(2000 + year, month);`? Is the year in an `int`? Can it come in 2 digits or also 4 digits? Please post more information as to why the direct solution doesn't satisfy you.

Comment: If you want it to be interpreted as a year in the 20th century, add 1900 instead of 2000. (Or did you mean 21st century?). Anyway, what's wrong with adding 1900 or 2000? There's no way to automatically let `YearMonth` do that for you.

Comment: @Tunaki as written the year value is always provided as a two-digit value.

Comment: @Jesper sorry, I indeed ment the `21st` century. So adding 2000.

Answer (score 3):

The YearMonth class is designed to represent the full range of Years, from -999,999,999 (MIN_YEAR) to 999,999,999 (MAX_YEAR). Because of that, a two digit year (or indeed any number in that range) is a valid input and will be represented as "that year".

If you want to have a more restrictive behaviour then you would need to create your own class that exposed all of the methods of YearMonth and then modify the constructor to deal with the special case of one and two digit years that you would like.

Answer (score 1):

As far as understand you concern is about mapping to the current century somehow dynamic. What about this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(mapToCurrentCentury(16, 11));
    System.out.println(mapToCurrentCentury(116, 11));
    System.out.println(mapToCurrentCentury(1116, 11));
}

private static YearMonth mapToCurrentCentury(int year, int month) {
    if(year < 1000) {
        YearMonth now = YearMonth.now();
        return now.withYear(((now.get(ChronoField.YEAR) / 1000) * 1000) + (year % 1000)).withMonth(month);
    }
    else {
        return YearMonth.of(year, month);
    }
}
```

It handles the mapping to your current century, but also recognizes about an *absolute* year value.

Output is:

```
2016-11
2116-11
1116-11
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have the input values as String in the format YY-MM, you could parse the String using a `DateTimeFormatter`

```
DateTimeFormatter YYMM = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy-MM");
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse("16-11", YYMM);
```

But as you already have an `int`, there is nothing wrong with just adding 2000.